# Reading integers > 9 in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, real-mode

I want to read `integers` from input in `x86` assembly but have some problems doing so when the `integer` is bigger than 9.

I tried the following code (found in internet) :

```
.code
  mov bh,0
  mov bl,10
inputloop:
  mov ah,1
  int 21h
  cmp al,13
jne convertion
jmp startcalc

convertion:
  sub al,48
  mov cl,al
  mov al,bh
  mul bl
  add al,cl
  mov bh,al
jmp inputloop    

startcalc:
```

I want my program to store the correct number in `ax` register at the start of `startcalc` label.

What should I do and what should I change in this program?

Comment: the code looks to store the correct amount in ax(lo) but there is an additional 1 in ax(hi)

Comment: Why could that be? Do you suppose maybe because you did `mov ah,1`?

Comment: what should i do instead of mov ah,1?

Comment: No way around that, as the interrupt needs it. You just have to save/restore `ax` or use a different register. Actually not sure where you expect your result.

Comment: at the start of startcalc label I want the input to be saved at ax register ... everything is correct but for example when I enter 132, in lo I correctly have 0D but in hi I have 01 ... I should have 00 instead

Comment: Also depends on what range you expect. If only up to 255 then you can just zero `ah` and be done with it. If you want bigger numbers, you will have to use a 16 bit register.

Comment: thanks a lot , i'll try again :)

Comment: Let's say for example, you were to enter "3172". What do you expect the result in AX to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! My! That code limits your input to a number within 1 byte, so between 0 and 255.

Using `bx` to store the result, I would use something like this:

```
  mov bx, 0

inputloop:

  mov ah, 1   ; getc()
  int 21h

  cmp al, 13  ; enter?
  je startcalc

  sub al, 48  ; character to number (assuming user only types '0' to '9')
  mov ah, 0   ; clear ah

  sll bx, 1   ; x2
  mov cx, bx
  sll bx, 2   ; x4 (so x8 total)
  add bx, cx  ; x2 + x8 = x10
  add bx, ax

  jmp inputloop

startcalc:
   mov ax, bx  ; if you want the result in ax instead
```

Now your number is between 0 and 65535, at least.

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you get wrong answer in `AX` ?**

You stop the process of aggregating integers whenever user hits enter key. So when the user hits enter key, the aggregated integer stored in `AX` will be replace by `010D`. `01` because its the service of INT 21h that you are using to get an integer from the keyboard (which will replace the contents of `AH` to `01`). And `0D` because its the hex value of enter key (which will replace the contents of `AL` to `0D`). So the value of `AX` register is no longer storing the result (the aggregated integer).

**How to fix it ?**

> I want my program to store the correct number in ax register at the start of startcalc label.

Simply add these lines of code at the start of your `startcalc` label like this:

```
startcalc:

     mov ah, 0     ; Get rid of 01 in AH
     mov bl, 0     ; Get rid of 0A in BL 
     mov al, bh    ; Store the result in AL
```

Now you can access the `AX` which stores the correct result.

As [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester) said if you want bigger numbers you will have to use 16bit registers and this can be done with the following:

**Code for 16bit number:**

To allow your program to accept 16bit number do the following:

Replace this :

```
mov bh,0
mov bl,10
```

By this :

```
mov bx, 0    
mov di,10    ; DI is a 16bit register that will store our divisor
```

And this :-

```
sub al,48
mov cl,al
mov al,bh
mul bl
add al,cl
mov bh,al
```

By this :-

```
sub al, 48
mov ah, 0
mov cx,ax       ; using 16bit version of CX and AX (store AX into CX)
mov ax,bx       ; store the previous value of BX into AX  
mul di          ; multiple the AX with DI  
add ax,cx       ; add the current integer (CX) with the multiplication result 
mov bx,ax       ; store AX into BX
```

And then finally this :-

```
startcalc:

     mov ah, 0
     mov bl, 0
     mov al, bh
```

By this :-

```
startcalc: 

     mov ax, bx
```

Hope that helps. :)